# Rest Client for Applets?

Tags: java, spring, rest, applet, httpurlconnection

Is there a 'de facto' REST client for Applets? I need to send POJOs mapped as JSON by Jackson to a Spring MVC controller. The obvious choice would be Spring Android, as it has a cut-down version of the `RestTemplate` functionality, but it apparently also has some functionality specific to working out which Android version is being run.

Are there easy way to accomplish this?

I've tried doing this 'manually' using `HTTPUrlConnection`, but I never see the request turn up in the controller:

```
URL url = new URL("http", getDomain(), 8080, getBaseUrl()+"save");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + getSessionId());

connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    
connection.connect();           

OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();

mapper.writeValue(out, state);

out.flush();
out.close();
connection.disconnect();
```